# Результат поиска по нескольким индексам Sphinx

Tags: php, sphinx

В результирующем массиве поиска по индексам sphinx, попадают все найденные совпадения из разных индексов, но почему-то массив формируется только набором полей (**fields**) для первого индекса article:

```
array(10) {
  ["error"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["warning"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["status"]=>
  int(0)
  ["fields"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "articletime"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "articlename"
    [2]=>
    string(18) "articledescription"
    [3]=>
    string(11) "articletext"
  }
  ["attrs"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["type"]=>
    int(1)
    ["idn"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  ["matches"]=>
  array(4) {
    [483]=>
    array(2) {
      ["weight"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["attrs"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["idn"]=>
        string(2) "48"
      }
    }
    [542]=>
    array(2) {
      ["weight"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["attrs"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["idn"]=>
        string(2) "54"
      }
    }
    [713]=>
    array(2) {
      ["weight"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["attrs"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["idn"]=>
        string(2) "71"
      }
    }
    [723]=>
    array(2) {
      ["weight"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["attrs"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["idn"]=>
        string(2) "72"
      }
    }
  }
  ["total"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["total_found"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["time"]=>
  string(5) "0.002"
  ["words"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["nova"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["docs"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["hits"]=>
      string(1) "8"
    }
  }
}
```

Т-е обрабатывая результат **matches** я могу вывести значения полей только первого индекса

Пример конфига, представлено 2 индекса:
    #articles
    source articles : lsParentSource
    {

```
     sql_query_range   = SELECT MIN(idArticle), MAX(idArticle) FROM article
     sql_range_step    = 128
     sql_query_pre     = SET NAMES utf8
     sql_query         = \
            SELECT idArticle * 10 + 2 as id, 1 as type, idarticle, idArticle as idn, articlecountry, articletime, articletouserid, articlecategory, ArticleName, ArticleDescription, ArticleText FROM article WHERE idArticle >= $start AND idArticle <= $end
     sql_attr_uint     = idArticle
     sql_attr_uint     = type
     sql_attr_uint    = idn
     sql_attr_uint     = ArticleToUserID
     sql_attr_uint     = ArticleCategory
     sql_attr_uint     = ArticleCountry
     sql_field_string  = ArticleTime
     sql_field_string  = ArticleName
     sql_field_string  = ArticleDescription
     sql_field_string  = ArticleText
     sql_query_info    = SELECT ArticleName, ArticleText \
                         FROM article WHERE idArticle = ($id - 2) / 10
}

#news
source news : lsParentSource
{

     sql_query_range   = SELECT MIN(idNew), MAX(idNew) FROM new
     sql_range_step    = 128
     sql_query_pre     = SET NAMES utf8
     sql_query         = \
            SELECT idNew * 10 + 3 as id, 3 as type, NewName, idnew, idNew as idn, newtouserid, newcategory, newcountry, NewDescription, NewText, NewTime FROM new WHERE idNew >= $start AND idNew <= $end
     sql_attr_uint     = idNew
     sql_attr_uint     = type
     sql_attr_uint    = idn
     sql_attr_uint     = NewToUserID
     sql_attr_uint     = NewCategory
     sql_attr_uint     = NewCountry
     sql_attr_uint     = NewTime
     sql_field_string   = NewName
     sql_field_string  = NewDescription
     sql_field_string  = NewText
     sql_query_info    = SELECT NewName, NewText \
                         FROM new WHERE idNew = ($id - 3) / 10
}
```

Comment: Так а вопрос то в чем?

И приведите пример конфига сфинкса

Comment: Смотрите, в массиве 4 найденных совпадения matches. 
Но в этом массиве почему-то всего 2 атрибута: type, idn.
В дополнение к вопросу прикрепляю конфиг

Comment: Что скажете?

Comment: По всей видимости, это совпадающие атрибуты, которые есть и в том, и другом индексе

Comment: Kak rewiti vopros? vedi imena to atributov raznie

Comment: Так а вопрос то в чем? Из ваших слов вообще непонятно чего вы хотите добиться ;-)

Если ожидаете увидеть в ответе разные поля из первого и из второго индексов, то ничего не получится - сфинкс в этом плане работает на подобии UNION в SQL, т.е. в результат попадут только те поля, которые есть в обоих индексах одновременно.

Если не подходит, сделайте два запроса с явным указанием индекса, который использовать, а дальше объедините результаты так, как вам надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Если ожидаете увидеть в ответе" - здесь появился луч в темном царстве...об этом я не знаю. Но не понимаю, если поиск происходит по разным индексам (таблицам) - то не логично, что получить результаты от разных индексов - невозможно. Если я вас понял, то если сфинкс нашел 3 записи из индекса (таблицы) articles и 1 запись из индекса news, то результатом будет ТОЛЬКО 3 записи из articles?